# Retain data on page refresh using Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service in Angular which contains a **Behaviour Subject** that gets an initial value from the database and gets new values from a form.

Currently, once the user fills out the form to filter a search and refreshes the page, the form would get the values from the database and not the last applied values.

Is there a way to retain the data once the user refreshes the page without using local/session storage but using Rxjs and angular?

Comment: Nope. You need to store it somewhere.

Comment: @AdithyaSreyaj local/session storage and cookies are the only places where I can store them?

Comment: You could persist it also in a database but all your Angular/RxJs states get wiped on refreshing a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your form doesn't contain a lot of inputs, You can create a state object and encode it in Base64 and append it to the URL.
And on page Load you can fill the form using it.

Comment: Beat me to it. This gives you an advantage over local storage as URLs can be shared the state that is loaded will be the same for every user.

Comment: storing the data in URL is not safe. it is better you save it in secure store (backend if you want to share the URL ) or browser storage with encryption algorithm.but if security is not important to you .take it easy.